# Can't install pgAdmin4

Tags: pgadmin

I am trying to install **pgAdmin4** on **Ubuntu 18.04** following [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu/), but I get the following error with command `pip install pgadmin4-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`:

```
src/_fastmath.c:31:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/hugolvc/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-Eiam7O/pycrypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-xfTq9G/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hugolvc/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4/include/site/python2.7/pycrypto" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-Eiam7O/pycrypto/
```

I just followed the tutorial step by step.

**EDIT**

The result of `python --version` is `Python 2.7.15rc1`, but I also have installed 3.6 and 3.7.

The result of `locate x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` is:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-5
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-5
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-7
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-5
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-7
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-5
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-7
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-5.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-5.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-5.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-5.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-7.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc.1.gz
```

The result of `sudo find / -name "Python.h"` is:

```
/home/hugolvc/.local/share/Trash/files/Python-3.7.0/Include/Python.h
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

Comment: you have python-dev installed?

Comment: Give `python --version` and post it. Also Type `locate x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` and output will be like `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc`

Comment: The `include "Python.h"` is missing in your system. Issue command `sudo find / -name "Python.h"` and output should be such as  `/usr/include/python3.7m/Python.h`, and/or `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h`.  Please @Hugo Luis Villalobos Canto, post all the output of commands as part of your question (i.e. edit your question and post!)

Comment: Just now, I tried to install  `pgAdmin4` based on your [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu/) and I was successful! I suspect that the  problem is with your Python installation. Type command  `python3 --version` and you should see output as `Python 3.6.7`. Have you run command such as `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python3-venv` during python installation?

Comment: FYI, after installation of  `pgAdmin4`, I typed `pip3 -V` whose output is `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)`

Comment: FYI, I installed `Python-3.6.7` from source and compiled. Downloaded `Python-3.6.7.tgz` using `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.7/Python-3.6.7.tgz`. Ran the configure script to check the build `./configure` followed by `make` and then `sudo make install`. In order to install any  missing package run:`$ sudo apt install zlib1g-dev`, **That is it!** Then check version by `python3 --version`.

Comment: @Marmayogi, I added the information. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have your `Python.h` in `~/.local/share/Trash/files/Python-3.7.0/Include` whose version is `3.7.0`. Whereas `python --version` outputs `Python 2.7.15rc1`. Please observe, "why version command did not show up `3.7.0`? Moreover, you have installed `Python.h` locally in your home,  no doubt, but `pgAdmin4` could not locate your `Python.h`, so your compilation terminated. Hope you see my point. Please post the output of command `env | grep $PWD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `python-dev` package using the command below:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python-dev   # for python2
sudo apt-get install python3-dev  # for python3
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Do you use `pip3` or `pip`? You must install `python3-dev` for `pip3`.

Comment: Ok, that was it. It worked. Thanks a lot!!!